# How to get Current Rendered UserControls In MainWindow as a Child?

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, user-controls, navigation

I am new to MVVM and using MVVMLight Toolkit. Thus i am working on project where Navigation Take place using based on Uri which is set on Frame exposed on View as x:Name.
 Here is my Code..

```
public  virtual void SetFrame(Uri userControll, string FrameElementName)
{
     var mainWindow = Application.Current.MainWindow;
     var frame = mainWindow.FindName(FrameElementName) as Frame;

     if (frame != null)
     {
          frame.Source = userControll;
     }
 }
```

If we Want navigation function to Work on Currently Rendered UserControll Which is child of MainWindow? What steps we have to perform?
Like

```
public  virtual void SetFrame(Uri anotherUserControll, string FrameElementName)
{
     var userControl= // what to do to get Currently rendered Usercontroll as child of MainWindow?
     var frame = userControl.FindName(FrameElementName) as Frame;

     if (frame != null)
     {
        frame.Source = anotherUserControll;      
     }
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved this problem by casting Frame.Context as UserControl to get the Current Rendered UserControl.. 
Here

```
    public  virtual void SetFrame(Uri anotherUserControll, string FrameElementName)
     {
         var mainFrame =(Frame)Application.Current.MainWindow.FindName("MainFrame");
         var userControll = mainFrame.Content as UserControl;
         var frame = userControll.FindName(contentControll) as Frame;
         if (frame != null)
         {
             frame.Source = anotherUserControll;
         }           
     }
```